# Refer a label of a chapter in another chapter

Tags: cross-referencing

I am writing a thesis in `LaTeX`. I need to refer a label of a chapter in another chapter. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Please explain in more than just one sentence what you are trying to achieve. Are you looking for `\ref{<label>}`?

Comment: Yes. But, \ref<label> does not show the labels of another chapter.

Comment: It should, so a minimal (non-)working example would be necessary.

Comment: From Chapter 4, I want to see Section \ref{<label>} of Chapter \ref{Chapter3}. However, in \ref{<label>}, no label from Chapter \ref{Chapter3} can be seen. I have also used cleveref package and tried \cref{<label>} instead of \ref{<label>}.

Comment: Have you split up chapters into different files and then compiling the master file?

Comment: Yes. Chapters are split up into different files. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you including the several chapter files at all?

Comment: Yes, there are several chapter files (chapters are split up into different files). From Chapter 4, I want to see Section \ref{<label>} of Chapter \ref{Chapter3}. However, in \ref{<label>}, no label from Chapter \ref{Chapter3} can be seen. I have also used cleveref package and tried \cref{<label>} instead of \ref{<label>}. Please give me a suggestion.

Comment: @Nasim: You're just repeating your previous comment. That's not helpful. Provide a compilable minimal version of your document, that is compilable and add it to your question above, please. And is there a `\label{...}` command at all in your files?

Comment: @ Hupfer Can you please give me a small example that shows labels of a different chapter (in different file also) in another chapter? I have just one label (\label{C3:Experiment}) in a chapter that needs to be referred from a different chapter. All chapters are in different files. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: That they are in different files shouldn't matter, as long as the files are all used in the same document, with e.g. `\input` or `\include`. Each chapter file doesn't have a `\documentclass` and packages, does it?

Comment: `\documentclass{book}\begin{document}\include{chap1}\include{chap2}\end{document}`. `chap1.tex` has `\chapter{A}\label{a}`, `chap2.tex` has `\chapter{B}See \ref{a}.` That should work.

Comment: @Nasim: You have to use the username, not something like `@ Hupfer` -- this won't work to address somebody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works completely out of the box, using `filecontents` just for easy generation of dummy chapter files with some content.

A `\ref` or `\cref` statement requires the label name, which has to be specified first for the relevant entity to be labelled!

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{filecontents}{nasimchapterone}
  \chapter{Nasim One}\label{chap:one}

  In \Cref{chap:two} or \Cref{chap:three,chap:four} we will see that
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{nasimchaptertwo}
  \chapter{Nasim Two}\label{chap:two}

  In \Cref{chap:one} or \Cref{chap:three,chap:four} we will see that
\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{nasimchapterthree}
  \chapter{Nasim Three}\label{chap:three}

  In \Cref{chap:three} or \Cref{chap:one,chap:two} we will see that
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{nasimchapterfour}
  \chapter{Nasim Four}\label{chap:four}

  In \Cref{chap:one,chap:three} we have seen that
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{nasimchapterone}
\include{nasimchaptertwo}
\include{nasimchapterthree}
\include{nasimchapterfour}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) `<nitpicking>` `\Cref` is supposed to be used at the start sentences, `\cref` within sentences. `</nitpicking>`

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: German style -- uppercase usage :-P (Thanks )

Comment: `\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}`.